# RadContextMenu closes on button click

Tags: javascript, telerik, contextmenu, rad-controls

I am trying to make my RadContextMenu stay open when use the left click. It works find when i use the right mouse click because that is the default, but i also want to open the context menu on right click, it closes straight away as soon as it is opened.

**Layout**

```
    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnGenerate" runat="server"
        Text="Generate..." ToolTip="Click to generate the tracking/tags/preview for the current creative"
        OnClientClicked="generateMenuItemOnLeftClick">
    </telerik:RadButton>
    <telerik:RadContextMenu ID="cmGenerate" runat="server" Flow="Horizontal"
        OnItemClick="cmGenerate_ItemClick" OnClientItemClicking="generateMenuItemClicking">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Generate Tracking" Value="generateTracking" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Generate Preview" Value="generatePreview" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Generate Tags" Value="generateTags" />
        </Items>
        <Targets>
            <telerik:ContextMenuControlTarget ControlID="btnGenerate" />
        </Targets>
    </telerik:RadContextMenu>
```

**JS**

```
        function generateMenuItemOnLeftClick(sender, eventArgs) {
            var currentLocation = $telerik.getLocation(sender.get_element());
            var contextMenu = $find("<%=cmGenerate.ClientID%>");
            contextMenu.showAt(currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y + 22);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for other people who have the same issue. I found that you have to call

> ```
> $telerik.cancelRawEvent(event);
> ```

right after a showAt(..) method. This cancels the default behavior which is the instant close.